# Transform Value In PlayJSon Mapping

Tags: scala, playframework, play-json

I'm performing a standard mapping of JSON to a case class using PlayJson. I'd like to transform the value that gets mapped to a member, `Test.foo` below, if the validation succeeds. Is it possible to work that into the definition of a Reads converter?

```
val json = .....

case class Test(foo:String, bar:String)

val readsTest: Reads[Test] = (
  (__ \ "foo").read[String](minLength(5)) and // And I want to transform this value if the validation succeeds
  (__ \ "bar").read[String](minLength(10))
)(Test.apply _)


json.validate[Test] match {
  case s: JsSuccess[Test] => s.get
  case e: JsError => false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Reads.map`](https://github.com/playframework/play-json/blob/dc2f1458e7060f4a4a16b08e3c021b2d7b852642/play-json/shared/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/Reads.scala#L51) can do just that, for example, say we want to reverse the value of `foo` field, then we could call `.map(v => v.reverse)` on the `Reads` like so

```
(__ \ "foo").read[String](minLength[String](5)).map(v => v.reverse)
```

Here is a working example

```
val json =
  """
    |{
    |  "foo": "abcdefghijkl",
    |  "bar": "012345678910"
    |}
    |""".stripMargin

case class Test(foo: String, bar: String)

val readsTest: Reads[Test] = (
  (__ \ "foo").read[String](minLength[String](5)).map(v => v.reverse)
  (__ \ "bar").read[String](minLength[String](10))
)(Test.apply _)

Json.parse(json).validate[Test](readsTest)
```

which outputs

```
JsSuccess(Test(lkjihgfedcba,012345678910),)
```

Comment: Appreciate you!

Comment: @ILovePhotos you should accept this as answer when it solves your problem.

Comment: @cbley Is that the green checkbox to the right? Thanks for pointing that out.